# Week Calculation Based On Start Date and Day

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a need to calculate date Week of a given financial year based on given start date and start day (Monday/Sunday) of week i.e. if i will set start day as Monday my Week should start from Monday. And also need to show that week date is weekly off or not

Week calculation configuration table is like below : -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Start_Date</th>
    <th>Week_Start</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>04-04-2018</td>
    <td>Monday</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

weekly off configuration table for showing one flag that day is Weekly off or not : -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Frequency</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>Bi Weekly 15</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Need result like : -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>WeekNumber</th>
    <th>WeekOff</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>04-04-2018</td>
    <td>WK1</td>
    <td>false</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>05-04-2018</td>
    <td>WK1</td>
    <td>false</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>06-04-2018</td>
    <td>WK1</td>
    <td>false</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>07-04-2018</td>
    <td>WK1</td>
    <td>false</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>08-04-2018</td>
    <td>WK1</td>
    <td>true</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>09-04-2018</td>
    <td>WK2</td>
    <td>false</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>-----</td>
    <td>-----</td>
    <td>-----</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31-03-2019</td>
    <td>WK52</td>
    <td>false</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So is it SQL Server or MySQL? Can't be both eventhough you tagged both. Also, you're showing generated HTML's with some data... I presume you just want to know how to pull that kind of data from week tables that are like the ones in week HTML's you gave?

Comment: @MK_,it is for MySQL

Comment: please update the tag accordingly